# No sound on Ubuntu 16.04 with realtek ALC892

Tags: drivers, 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

## My problem

I do not get any sound from any of my analog connectors. HDMI output from the Radeon card is working fine when i select that in pavucontrol.

All jacks are showing (unplugged) in pavucontrol wether cable is plugged in or not.

This is not a fresh install, but i encounter the same problem when booting from a live disk.

My hardware:

- Asus M5A99FX PRO R2.0
- AMD Radeon 7950

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04.

---

#### Some info

You can find my alsa-info.sh output here: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=6dd562654110341b541e4169680a9bff855a159d

lspci -v | grep -A7 Audio

```
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
Memory at feb00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

--
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7870 XT / 7950/7970]
Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Tahiti XT HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7970 Series]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
Memory at fea60000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
#install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
#install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
#install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }

# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
#options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
```

---

#### What i've tried

I've tried (among other things):

- All the obvious stuff (headphones are working, alsamixer is not muted, etc)
- Making sure that audio device is enabled in bios
- Toggling front audio in bios between AC97 & HD
- Installing realtek drivers from their site.
- Adding "options snd-hda-intel model=auto" & other models to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS
- Disabling / enabling loopback & automute in alsamixer
- Using multiple built-in audio profiles in pavucontrol
- Using multiple ports in pavucontrol
- Using one of the latest kernels to get new alsa driver
- Reinstalling alsa & pulseaudio
- Killing the pulse daemon and testing sound with:

  aplay -D plughw:0,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav

  speaker-test -c 2 -t wav
- Renaming /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf to make alsa use defaults
- Disabling jack detection with hdajackretask
- Retasking rear green line out to other options with hdajackretask
- Testing sound output from a fresh windows install (which worked...)

---

#### Pulse errors

I noticed something that i think is causing this, but i can't find any relevant solutions on the web.

Pulse is logging thousands of messages like this in debug mode.

```
Nov  1 17:09:44 synapse pulseaudio[2445]: [alsa-source-ALC892 Analog] alsa-source.c: Overrun!
Nov  1 17:09:46 synapse pulseaudio[2445]: message repeated 10 times: [ [alsa-source-ALC892 Analog] alsa-source.c: Overrun!]
```

---

I've been debugging this issue for 2 days now. This is the first problem with ubuntu i have not been able to solve by myself.

Any advice would be appreciated. When you need more information about my system, please ask.

Comment: What error is reported by your aplay test?

Comment: @laugeo No errors are reported by aplay

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. The first time i did an upgrade from 14 lts to 16 and surprise, no sound. 
After then i do a new installation without any results by default.

The next steps work for me:

1. Open a terminal and type alsamixer, with the card *HDA ATI SB* with chip *Realtek ALC892*, turn *auto-mute* to *disabled*.
2. After that i'd install Pulse Audio Volume control.
3. Open it Pulse Audio Volume Control and in  Configuration tab you can see the *ATI HDMI Digital Setereo* and *Internal Audio*. Select to Internal Audio: *Stereo Analog Duplex* (Estéreo analógico duplex).
4. In Pulse Audio Volume, select *Ouput devices*, and for Internal Analog Stereo select: analg headphones.

Important: You must have installed the ATI drivers first.
D Atonaltzin

Motherboard Gigabyte GA-880GM-USB3 (realtek ALC892 audio integrated), AMD Phenom II, 4GB RAM, Ati Radeon RX460 2GB graphics card.alsamix

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I'm using a USB Logitech Headset and set both, the nvidia HDA and the Intel HDA to "off". No clipping, lagging anymore .. !

Comment: It's 2019 on Ubuntu 18.04 and my sound on this system config just spontaneously stopped working after a reboot. Your procedure helped me restore sound output. Thank you for taking the time to write this up.