# Randomly getting "Dummy output" and no sound

Tags: sound

At various times, sound is not working after boot up. I would like to know if this is a hardware problem or a software problem. And why it is happening randomly.

I have the following:

- Alsa-info (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo)
- pulseverbose-log (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio/Log)
- Output from the sound trouble shooting guide (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4.

My computer is a Clevo N350TW.

Output from `cat /proc/asound/car*/co* |  grep Codec` when the sound is working is:

```
Codec: Realtek ALC892
Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI
```

(When the sound is not working, "Realtek ALC892" is missing from the output.)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, please edit your Question and add your Ubuntu version i.e. 20.04/18.04 etc and type of output devices.

Comment: Here is alsa-info when sound is _not_ working: https://pastebin.com/hQG1mWuz

Comment: Here is alsa-info when sound _is_ working: https://pastebin.com/pFUKnRsc

Comment: This might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/844284/no-sound-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-realtek-alc892, if not, the computer needs a new solution for the Realtek sound driver.

Comment: Hello Sadaharu-san! I followed the steps in the link. Hope that it helps; only time will tell. (Kindly note that I _randomly_ get this problem...) I did not download the commercial drivers, since they were dated 2018 Aug 08 and RealTek states "only support kernel version under 3.18". My Linux version is 5.4.0... Anyway, thank You for Your kind support!!